# Modify Accept-Language Request Header using IIS

Tags: iis-7.5, iis-8

I'm looking for a way to set the "Accept-Language" to a specific value for all incoming request. I use IIS 7.5+. I have looked at the rewrite module but can't seem to find the right combination to set the request header.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer. By using the Rewrite Module, and add a rule that runs on all incoming request [.*], and set the server-variable "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE" to whatever the required setting.